# Getting Database in array and using it outside with foreach statement like and Opencart

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, foreach

I have seen the opencart function which can be used outside with html like

```
<?php

    foreach ($categories as $category){
        echo $category['image'];
    }

?>
```

i would like to make a function like that in php which i can grab data from database and use it outside. may be it's an array so foreach statement is working on it.

like i have name and age in my database i would like to use it like this

```
<?php
    foreach($peoples as $people){
        echo $people['name'];
        echo $people['age'];
    } 
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: go to google and search for get database results as array. Try, a little.

Comment: or search through stack overflow, theres thousands of questions like this (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8237428/1524085)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aman Chhabra mentioned, you must first fetch the result from database and then you can use `foreach` loop to iterate over it.
One thing I would like to mention is DON'T use `mysql_query()` as use of it is discouraged as per the new guidelines of php development (Check: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). To have a compatible code with advanced php use `mysqli_query()` instead.
Following is the code example utilizing mysqli class. This is procedural way but you can use it in OOP style as well.

```
//Connect to database
$host = "localhost"; //Change according to yours
$username = "root"; //Change according to yours
$password = ""; //Change according to yours
$database = "test"; //Change according to yours

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database); //Create the connection
if(!$con)
{
    echo "Not connected";
}
else
{
    echo "Connected<br />";
}

//Prepare the query to fetch the database records
$query = "select * from TableName"; //Replace the table name with yours
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$query); //Execute the query
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) //Loop through, till there are records corresponding to the query
{
    $rows[] = $result; //Store all the records in an array
}

//Now iterate over each property using foreach loop
foreach($rows as $row)
  {
      echo "Name - ".$row['name']." Age - ".$row['age']."<br />";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev. I am glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart modifies it to the array of results and the use it using foreach

You need to do it like this

```
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $data[] = $result;
      }
```

And then later you can use it like this

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
   echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
      echo "<br>";
}
```